# Underscore/Lodash выбор данных _.where

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

я отбираю на underscore данные

```
_.where(StudentsGroupList, {"GroupId": 1});
```

а как мне отобрать, где значения "GroupId" 1,2,3,4,5 ? 
Этим методом он не перебирает по одинаковым полям.
можете привести пример на underscore  или lodash с where или с другой функцией перебора?

так же делал

```
_.filter(StudentsExamList, function(num){ return num.GroupId == 5; });
```

Но как вместо 5 подставить массив?

Answer (score 1):

[`range`](http://underscorejs.org/#range) — диапазон с 1 по 5;

[`contains`](http://underscorejs.org/#contains) — наличие элемента в коллекции;

```
var range = _.range(1, 5);
var res = _.filter(StudentsExamList, function(exam){ 
   return _.contains(range, exam.GroupId) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например, так:

```
_.filter(StudentsExamList, function(item){
    return (_.indexOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], item.GroupId) !== -1);
});
```